# queryset in admin.py never gets executed in django 2.2

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

My code was originally implemented for Django 1.8 now (after necessary changes) I'm running it with Django 2.2. Seems that the following was planned to show non-super-user only his/her own files:

```
class Tiedostot3Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['otsikko', 'kuvaus', 'tiedosto']
    list_display = ('otsikko','paivitetty')
    inlines = [
      Liitet3Inline,
  ]
    def queryset(self, request):
        print("queryset, request.user", request.user)
        qs = super(Tiedostot3Admin, self).queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)
        
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print("save_model, request.user", request.user)
        obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
```

When saving new files I can see `save_model()` executed, but I don't know how to get queryset() executed. It seems that it always shows the same list for all users.

models.py:

```
class Tiedostot3(models.Model):
    otsikko = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    kuvaus = RichTextField(blank=True)
    paivitetty = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Päivitetty")
    tiedosto = models.FileField(upload_to='poytakirjat', verbose_name="Tiedosto", blank = True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-paivitetty']
        verbose_name = "tiedosto"
        verbose_name_plural="tiedostot"
        
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.otsikko)
        
class Liite3(models.Model):
    otsikko = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    tiedosto = models.FileField(upload_to='poytakirjat')
    doku = models.ForeignKey(Tiedostot3, related_name="liitteet", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural="Liitteet"
    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.otsikko)
```

the page: [image]

Comment: Try `get_queryset`. `ModelAdmin` doesn't define a `queryset` method (maybe it did in 1.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `get_queryset` method:

```py
class Tiedostot3Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['otsikko', 'kuvaus', 'tiedosto']
    list_display = ['otsikko','paivitetty']
    inlines = [Liitet3Inline]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
       qs = super(Tiedostot3Admin, self).get_queryset(request)
       if request.user.is_superuser:
          return qs
       return qs.filter(owner=request.user)
        
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        print("save_model, request.user", request.user)
        obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()
```